# Parsing PyQt output (rendered w/ JS) with beautiful soup

Tags: python, parsing, pyqt, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've been unable to find an effective way to capture rendered HTML (using PyQt) and parse said HTML with beautiful soup.  Perhaps I'm not storing the HTML properly.  I've tried using requests, but thus far with little success.

Thanks in advance!

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  
from lxml import html 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import codecs
import time
import unicodecsv

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")

title_strings = open("title_test.txt","rb")

output = "title_string_out.txt"
csv_writer = unicodecsv.writer((open(output, "wb")), delimiter="|", quotechar = '"', encoding = "utf-8")

row = []

class Render(QWebPage):  
    def __init__(self, url):  
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
        QWebPage.__init__(self)  
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
        self.app.exec_()  

    def _loadFinished(self, result):  
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
        self.app.quit()  

titleURL = "URL_goes_here.html"
r = Render(titleURL)  
result = r.frame.toHtml()
result = str(result)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result) 

try:
    newtitle = soup.find("div", id = "soupstuff").find_all("div", class_ = "name")
    for n in newtitle:
        n = n.find("a").text
        row.append(str(newtitle))
except AttributeError:
    pass

csv_writer.writerow(row)

time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? What errors did you receive? What was the expected output, and how does that differ from the actual output?

Comment: I'm seeing the HTML generated on screen during print, but I'm unable to work with it in any way.  The problem is how do I capture and store the rendered HTML using the beautiful soup library.  Thanks!

Comment: You need to be much more specific, and edit your question accordingly.